# Horizontal legends in QGIS: Rendering columns from right to left

Tags: qgis, legend

I’m working on a mapping project in a right-to-left language and I’m using horizontal legends **with multiple columns** in my layout. I’ve already set the title of my legend elements to right, but it seems that there’s no option to set the alignment of the columns themselves – the first column is fixed to the left.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Please note that I’m using the atlas feature for automating the production of hundreds of maps, so manual touchups are a non-solution for me.

Comment: If they spawn in left to right, is there a way you could systematically feed qgis the data for the legend elements backwards/reversed so that the last column is actually the first, leftmost, column?

Comment: Thank you @MidPiedmont for your advice. I have already attempted to change the order of the layers but it was not effective. In this case, the first column from the right only contains a few symbols, whereas the header for the layer is located in a different column.

Comment: I was about to suggest posing this question to qgis on their Github, but upon pulling it up, I see you've already done that. If you figure out a method, definitely come back and answer your own question here if you have the time, I'm curious what the solution will end up being